# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter... mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I put my view and controller in here, my problem is after when posting value I got this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteQuestionDo(Int32)' in 'Landing.UI.Areas.cpanel.Controllers.BestDestinationResultController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteQuestionDo(int id)
{
    Logic.BestDestination.BestDestinationLogic bestDestLigic = new Logic.BestDestination.BestDestinationLogic();
    bestDestLigic.deleteQuestion(id);
    return RedirectToAction("DeleteQuestion");
}
```

view:

```
@model Landing.UI.Areas.cpanel.Models.BestDestinationQuestionList
....
@Html.BeginForm("DeleteQuestionDo", "BestDestinationResult", FormMethod.Post)
{
    @foreach (var m in Model.BestDestQuesList)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="@m.QuestionId" />
        <br />
        <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteQuestionDo", "BestDestinationResult", new { id = m.QuestionId })">@m.Question</a>
        <input name="@m.QuestionId" type="submit"  value="حذف کامل سؤال"  />
    }
}
```

Comment: You view code is not making sense. You have a a form that has multiple hidden inputs with a name attribute that is invalid and could not bind to anything, and since it does not have a `value` attribute it does not submit any value. And you also have a link in the same method that goes to your `DeleteQuestionDo()` method.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to do here. Your deleting an object therefore it should be a `[HttpPost]` method, not a GET - i.e. delete your link from the view. What you should have is multiple forms within a loop, and you add a route value in the `BeginForm() method

Comment: sry that link(url.action) is a test to check my logic and I added value attribute  for hidden inputs but I got the same error.

Comment: Because the `name` does not match (your not generating `name="id"` -
 look at the html your generating). But the view makes no sense - you have one form but multiple inputs. When you hit the submit button it posts back all the name/value pairs of each input! (again, you need to create multiple forms, one for each question)

Comment: I put beginForm in foreach but still same error!

Comment: Then you obviously did it wrong - `@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteQuestionDo", "BestDestinationResult", new { id = item.QuestionId }, FormMethod.Post)) { <input type="submit" value="حذف کامل سؤال" /> }` inside your loop

Comment: But your POST method has `return RedirectToAction("DeleteQuestion");` which suggests you might be redirect back to the same view? If that is the case, you would be better off using ajax.

Comment: thanks, it's worked but I get 0 for all id, I check my input those was 0-6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151814/discussion-between-muhammad-ehsan-mirzaei-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are multiple issues with your code and your logic, including

- The parameter in your method is named `id` but your not generating
  any inputs with `name="id"` (they are named `1`, `2`, etc. - i.e. the
  values of the `QuestionId` property which is not a valid c# property
  name anyway)
- Your hidden inputs do not have a `value` attribute so would always
  post back null
- Your generating multiple links that make a GET to a method which does
  not exist
- Your use of `@Html.BeginForm(..)` is incorrect and does not generate
  a closing `</form>` tag - it needs to be `@using
  (Html.BeginForm(...))` or you need to include `Html.EndForm()`

Even if you did add the correct name and value attribute, you would be posting back an array of all the `QuestionId` values in your collection which would make no sense (you only want to delete one)

You need to generate a `<form>` for each item in your collection. Within each form, you could add a `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@m.QuestionId" />`, however its easier to just add the value as a route attribute.

Change your code to

```
@foreach (var m in Model.BestDestQuesList)
{
    <div>@m.Question</div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteQuestionDo", "BestDestinationResult", new { id = @m.QuestionId} ))
    { 
        <input type="submit"  value="حذف کامل سؤال"  />
    }
}
```

As a side note, your use of `return RedirectToAction("DeleteQuestion");` suggests you might be redirecting back to the same view. If that is the case, you should consider using ajax to submit the `QuestionId` value to the 'Delete' method (and in the success callback, remove the associated elements from the DOM) which will improve performance

Comment: I had same problem, and solved with checking and syncing the parameter name in both method and route config.